# Show Date as dddd Mmmm d, yyyy SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Trying to show the date as Thursday, August 2, 2018 format. Its stored as `20180802` in the table. The column type is set to `char`. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Show where? Format the data on the front end, just as you would format numbers and currencies.

Comment: Salman. I want to show the date in the results. Query is very simple:
SELECT Event_ID,Event_Name, Event_Date
FROM Events
The date in table is 20180801 format but I want to show the results as Thursday, August 2, 2018. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following with `DateName` and `convert` functions :

```
select DateName( month , q.dt )+' '+convert(char,day(q.dt))+', '+convert(char,year(q.dt))
  from        
     (
      select convert(date,'20180802') as dt
     ) q;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/185a6/33)

With respect to your last comment make your query as :

```
select DateName( weekday , q.dt )+' '+
       DateName( month , q.dt )+' '+
       convert(char,day(q.dt))+', '+convert(char,year(q.dt)) as "Date"
  from        
     (
      select convert(date,'20180802') as dt
     ) q;

Date
------------------------
Thursday, August 2, 2018
```

Comment: Im using MS SQL 2014 and I forgot to mention I need the day as well. See my edited question. Thanks

Comment: @sccar OK, you're welcome, I've just edited your DBMS Tag as `sql-server`.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance. I have just hit a wall today. How would I use this in my existing query of: SELECT        Event_ID
   , Event_Name
   , Event_Date

Comment: @sccar oh no, not problem, have you tried by yourself..?

Comment: I have tried your query and it gives me the result as August 2                   ,2018.  There is a long space between the year and the month and day. Also it doesn't show me the day.  In perfect world I need the dates to say Thursday, August 2, 2018.

Comment: @sccar then you should add `DateName( weekday , q.dt )+', '+` just after `select` keyword

Comment: I'm sorry its not working for me. This is how my query looks: SELECT        Event_ID,Event_Name, DateName( Weekday, q.dt)+', '+ convert(char,day(q.dt))+', '+ convert(char,year(q.dt))
from Events
where Event_Date > '20180801'

Comment: @sccar but you should replace `q.dt` with `Event_Date`(i.e.your column name) in your case.

Comment: Ok finally got it to work using this:
DateName(Weekday, Event_Date)+','+ DateName(Month, Event_Date)+',' + convert(char,day(Event_Date))+','+convert(char,year(Event_Date)) AS "Date" 
But there is a long gap between August 2, &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 2018.  How can I remove the space.

Comment: @sccar `&nbsp` should be related to your HTML code, please re-check it.

Comment: No it's showing me the spaces in the SQL Management Studio in the Results pane.

Comment: @sccar so, there's no problem with SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up doing it this way and it removed the spaces.
SELECT 
DateName(Weekday, Event_Date)+','+ DateName(Month, Event_Date)+',' + DateName(Day, Event_Date)+', ' + DateName(Year, Event_Date)AS "Date"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Barbaros Özhan response,

```
SELECT DateName(dw,q.dt) +', '+DateName(month, q.dt)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR, DAY(q.dt))+', '+CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(q.dt))
FROM
(
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '20180802') AS dt
) q;
```

Comment: Just be mindful that this is not optimized for large datasets. I am sure there are performance implications so use sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are 2014, you can use format().

Format() has some great functionality, but it is not known to be a performer.

Also, since your "date" is stored as a string, I would suggest try_convert() or try_cast() to allow for any unexpected data.

**Example**

```
Select format(try_convert(date,'20180802'),'dddd, MMMM d, yyyy')
```

**Returns**

```
Thursday, August 2, 2018
```